# How to use variables in a user defined command?

Tags: variables, path, user-commands, command

I have this user defined command:

```
command! PS silent! w | PlugSnapshot! ~/.vim/plugins/plugins.lock
```

How could I change it to take the filepath from a variable, something like this:

```
let PathToPluginsFolder =  ~/.vim/plugins
command! PS silent! w | PlugSnapshot! %%%PathToPluginsFolder%%%/plugins.lock
```

Comment: @statox The question is different, and the answer could've been very different.

Comment: I don’t think these are different questions: these are two variations of “how can I use a variable in a vimscript expression?”. By marking this question as a duplicate I’m not arguing against its quality, I just want to make sure that future users can get an answer to their question and I also make sure that we keep together the related contents to give all the answers a better visibility. However you can vote to reopen the question and if the community agrees it will be reopened :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can simply use `exec` and `.` to build the command:

```
let PathToPluginsFolder =  ~/.vim/plugins
command! PS silent! exec ':w | PlugSnapshot! ' . PathToPluginsFolder . '/plugins.lock'
```